# TypeScript chain function calls

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to have a type that allows me to chain functions that are not executed until after the initial argument is passed. The way I want it to work looks like this:

```
const getStringFromNumber = pipe()
    .then(add(1))
    .then(toString)
    .then(prepend('0', 5))
    .value()
```

For completeness, my imaginary functions are as follows

- `add` is a function that takes 1 argument (number) and returns another function that when executed with another argument, adds them (e.g. `add(1)(2) -> 3`
- `toString` is a function that transforms an argument and returns a string (e.g. `toString(1) -> "1"`
- `prepend` is a function that takes two arguments and returns another function that when executed with a string, will prepend the string until minimum length is reached (e.g. `"1" -> "00001"`)

In this case, `getStringFromNumber` should be a function and can be run like this:

```
const result = getStringFromNumber(5)
// result is "00006"
```

The functions from above don't have to return values - in fact, it's probably better if each of them returns a `thenable` interface, because it would give more flexibility, but the most important part is that the final argument that triggers the execution is supplied last (the type must be correct).

What is the correct type for `pipe` to achieve this functionality?

Comment: That's all great and so, but where's the question? What have you tried? what doesn't work?

Comment: @Thomas added the question, there's a couple things I've tried, but mostly I'm struggling to even write a function that would give me what I want.

Answer (score 2):

If only the type is of concern here, the following should answer the question.

```
type Thenable<R, F> = { 
  then: <T>(fn: (arg: R) => T) => Thenable<T, F>
  value: () => (arg: F) => R
}

function pipe() {
  return {
    then: <F, T>(fn: (arg: F) => T) => { return {} as Thenable<T, F> }
  }
}
```

The function `thenable()` returns an object of type `Thenable` with two properties `then` and `value`.

`then` is a generic function which takes an function `fn` as the parameter. The return type of `fn` is inferred to the generic type `T`. `T` can then be used for the return type of `then` which returns a `Thenable<T>`.

This leads to the correct type of `getStringFromNumber`.

```
const getStringFromNumber = pipe()
    .then(add(1))
    .then(toString)
    .value()

getStringFromNumber // (arg: number) => string
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#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-WGkRwVlw9ZBqz-L5AA)

Comment: Thank you, but I still see a couple problems - first, you've used `any`, and secondly, I would like the type of the final parameter to be forced to be a `number` (because in this example, add expects a `number`)

Comment: Example: `pipe().value()(5) // any`

Comment: @Artur - See my update

Comment: Thanks, proposed types calls do work and allow for chaining, but implementation of `pipe` is still a problem as I can't seem to be figure out actual recursive 
 implementation of `then`. I was able to make it work with `add`.

Comment: to add to my previous comment, I can make it work with JS, I can't make it work with types (even though the solution you provided works).

Comment: @Artur - [Here](https://tsplay.dev/WGRQJm) is how an implementation could look like.